# Using the hist() command to plot 2 columns, one with quantitative data and the other with qualitative data

Tags: r, histogram

I am looking to see the number of tourism related policy implementations in the world in 2010. The data if further broken down by states/provinces in those countries and we have how many policy implementations occurred per state/province. I have a table/excel that gives me the following columns: (there are more columns but these are the relevant ones)

I want to make a histogram that shows the number of policy implementations in 2010 on a state/province level.

The problem is that I have quantitative and qualitative data. And I am unsure how to turn that qualitative data into quantitative for the histogram.

[Excel chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBmFM.png)

My current code:

`hist(data.set$polimp2015)`

but I don't think its correct

I called the number of tourism related policy implementations column polimp2015 and my overall data set, data.set

How can I show the number of policy implementations in 2010 on a state/province level?

Comment: states/province state)

Comment: # of policy implementations in 2010 (polimp2015)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't add comments to your question. Edit your question and put in whatever it is those comments are to the body of the question. As the comments are, they make no sense at all. Please review the question and answers in the following link to improve your own question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: HI Sarah, unfortunately, "this gives me a very wonky chart" is not enough information for us to help. Please [edit] your question and paste the output of `dput(head(data.set))` (preferred) or provide the data in tab delimited form. Please also provide an image of the chart you are getting and annotate or describe how you hope the output will be different.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.